# Basic JQuery/Ajax post help

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm learning PHP and I don't know how to get this to even work. I need help writing the file that returns data for this JQuery $.post()

I don't know how to use firebug but Firefox's error console says "Error: no element found"

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<title>JQuery Test</title>
</head>

<body>

<a class="open" href="#" style="color:black; text-decoration:none;">Test File</a>

<br />

<pre id="Test">Hello</pre>

<script type="text/javascript">
$('.open').click(function(){
$.post('source.php', function(src){
    alert(src)
    $('#Test').html(src);
});
return false;
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The PHP file

```
<?php
echo "hi"
?>
```

Comment: How to get what to work? What are you expecting to happen and doesn't happen?

Comment: Also, the PHP opening tag is `<?php`, not `<?php>`.

Comment: Use fire bug to see what error you are getting etc.

Comment: I fixed the PHP opening tag and the #Test but I'm not getting anything from the PHP, all that happens is the "Hello" text is removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The test id selector is wrong please try below

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('.open').click(function(){
$.post('source.php', function(src){
    alert(src)
    $('#Test').html(src);
});

/*
$.post('source.php', {name: current}, function(src){
    codeBox.html(src);
});
*/

return false;
});
</script>
```

Comment: That made the "Hello" text disappeared

Comment: Yes it will be replaced by whatever you source.php returns as a response. What do you expect?

Comment: How do I set source.php to send back a response?

Comment: The client code is in place properly. Make sure source.php sever side code is error free.

Comment: source.php is on the main question post. All I have is an echo but shouldn't that do it?

Comment: Here you go ... sourrce.php is returning an XML response. Can you make sure it returns the proper reponse type?

Comment: When you directly access source.php in the browser what do you see?

Comment: Nothing, Firefox asks me what program to open it in. Chrome directly downloaded it.

Comment: There is some problem on your server. I think it is not configured properly for php execution. I think your question is answered but now you have a different problem. If you try any simple html page for testing you will see the content coming in Test div.

Comment: I was afraid of that. Well, thank's anyways I'll set this as answered.

Answer (score 0):

**You have numerous flaws in your script.**

```
The **$('Test').html(src);** will not work it should be **$('#Test').html(src);**

The **<?php>** should be just **<?php**
```